# Resizing the mmap shared memory with mremap fails

Tags: memory, fork, mmap

I am working on a project in which I need to share a large array of std::pairs between processes created with fork() API. The size of the array is not known at the start of the program. Later on, the parent process will communicate with child processes to determine the size of the array. Then it will resize the shared memory space by calling mremap() API.  I have had no luck so far in using mmap and mremap.
It seems to me that mremap() fails when the new size becomes larger than 4096 bytes ( system's page size?).

I have created a small example to help me understand the problem better. This code, create a shared memory using mmap(), then increase its size using mremap at multiple steps. There is only one process in this example.
I am also rounding up the size of the requested shared memory to 4096 bytes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h> /* pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>  /* _exit, fork */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* exit */
#include <errno.h>   /* errno */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string.h>
#include  <sys/ipc.h>
#include  <sys/shm.h>
#define page_size 4096
#define def_size  32

void write_shmem (long *shm_ptr, long npt)
{
    for (long pt = 0; pt < npt ; ++pt)
    {
        shm_ptr[pt] = 77;
        //std::cout << "shm_ptr[" << pt << "] = " <<  shm_ptr[pt] << "\n";
    }
}

long read_shmem (long *shm_ptr, long npt)
{
    long bad_indx = -1;
    for (long pt = 0; pt < npt ; ++pt)
    {
        if (shm_ptr[pt] != 77)
        {
            bad_indx = pt;
            break;
        }
    }
    return bad_indx;
}

int main ()
{

    void * add;
    long *shm_arcs;
    long padding = 0;
    long init_shmem_size = sizeof (long) *def_size;
    long resid = init_shmem_size % page_size;
    if (resid!=0) padding = page_size  - (init_shmem_size % page_size);
    //std::cout << " requested " << init_shmem_size << " bytes, translated to " << padding+init_shmem_size << "\n";
    init_shmem_size +=padding;
    add = mmap(NULL, init_shmem_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0); // initial size is set to npt.
    if (add == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        std::cout << "Mapped failed at parent \n";
        exit(-1);
    }
    shm_arcs = (long *) add;
    write_shmem (shm_arcs, def_size);
    long bd = read_shmem (shm_arcs, def_size);

    if (bd!=-1)
    {
        std::cout << "Shmem test failed at " << bd << "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    std::cout<<"Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address " << shm_arcs <<" data size: " << init_shmem_size << ".\n ";


    long *shm_new = shm_arcs;
    long nsize = def_size;
    for (int i = 0; i< 1000; i ++)
    {
        nsize += def_size;
        long bsize = nsize*sizeof(long);
        if ((bsize % page_size)!=0) padding = page_size  - (bsize % page_size);
        else padding = 0;
        //std::cout << nsize << " elements requested " << bsize << " bytes, translated to " << padding+bsize << "\n";
        bsize+=padding;
        add = mremap(shm_new, init_shmem_size, bsize , MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
        if (add != shm_new)
        {
            std::cout << "Old mem unmapped ---------------";
            munmap(shm_new, init_shmem_size);
        }
        if (add == MAP_FAILED)
        {
            std::cout << "Mapped failed at parent  at " << i << "\n";
            exit(-1);
        }
        shm_new = (long *) add;

        write_shmem (shm_new, nsize);
        long bd = read_shmem (shm_arcs, nsize);
        if (bd!=-1)
        {
            std::cout << "Shmem test failed at " << bd << "\n";
            exit(-1);
        }

        std::cout<< i << " - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address " << shm_new <<" with " << nsize << " elements, data size : " << bsize <<  ".\n ";

        init_shmem_size = bsize;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output of the code:
    Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 data size: 4096.

```
0 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 64 elements, data size : 4096.
 1 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 96 elements, data size : 4096.
 2 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 128 elements, data size : 4096.
 3 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 160 elements, data size : 4096.
 4 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 192 elements, data size : 4096.
 5 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 224 elements, data size : 4096.
 6 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 256 elements, data size : 4096.
 7 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 288 elements, data size : 4096.
 8 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 320 elements, data size : 4096.
 9 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 352 elements, data size : 4096.
10 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 384 elements, data size : 4096.
11 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 416 elements, data size : 4096.
12 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 448 elements, data size : 4096.
13 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 480 elements, data size : 4096.
14 - Parent: shared memory is created and verified at address 0x7f00ae91b000 with 512 elements, data size : 4096.
Bus error
```

I am running it on Linux. 
What am I doing wrong here? If this is not the best method to do this, I appreciate if you could point a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not attempt unmap the old addres after `mremap` as it is already unmapped and may overlap with the new address range. Your "Old mem unmapped" message will not be printed as `cout` is buffered and the process dies before the buffer is flushed.